# How to validate grub boot environment parameters with grubby

Tags: grub, rhel7, grub2

I am updating grub parameters in RHEL 7.0 with grubby command using
`/usr/sbin/grubby --update-kernel=ALL --args='isolcpus=14-24'`
followed by `/usr/sbin/grub2-install /dev/sda` and `reboot`

I very well understand the process to manually configure and validate boot parameters. I simply have to edit/check `/etc/default/grub` file and add/validate boot parameters in `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX` variable.

My question is: Can grubby or any other tool validate if a boot parameter is added. I am trying to avoid manual reads to grub file and string operations. E.g. in above example a command (or tool) should validate if `isolcpus` parameter is properly added to grub.

I have read grubby manual [here](http://linux.die.net/man/8/grubby) but couldn't figure out any relevant flag.